# Bootstrap collapse dynamic 'data-target' not working as desired

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

I wanna show some posts via bootstrap `collapse`. I set dynamic `data-target` and **id** in bootstrap collapse using **post id**. its not working.

```
     <div class="container">
      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <% hadiths.forEach(function(hadith){ %>
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#<%= hadith._id %>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<%= hadith._id %>">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
              <h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-11">
                <%= hadith.serial %>- <%= hadith.title %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </h3>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="<%= hadith._id %>" class="collapse id" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="card-body">
                  <%- hadith.description %>
            </div>
          </div>
    <% }); %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But if i add some string in front of `<%= hadith._id %>` then it works like `a<%= hadith._id %>`. I need to set it `<%= hadith._id %>`. Please tell me what i did wrong.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/fr3hdbx8/

Answer (score 1):

dose your `<%= hadith._id %>` start with a special-key or a number?
if so this could be the problem

Comment: `hadith._id ` is string like `5d656babc0888435447ae7c8`. It will differ for different posts.

Comment: i think there was some issue with IDs and Classes starting with numbers and special keys, could you try to use a String? starting with a char? if you need the id in the js, you could just add it as data-attribute

Somethink like `id="collaps-<%= [some index made by the foreach...]%>"`